# New uniqueidentifier on the go

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, uniqueidentifier, alter

I want to add a column for a table which would become a PRIMARY KEY and be of type uniqueidentifier. I have this, but I wonder if there is a faster (in fewer code lines) way?

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [id] [uniqueidentifier] 
    DEFAULT('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') NOT NULL
GO    
UPDATE [table] SET [id] = NEWID()
GO    
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_table_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
GO
```

Comment: Why don't you set the default to `NEWID()` rather than doing it in two steps? - because, presumably, you'd want new rows to get a value also). Also, `NEWID()` and `CLUSTERED` don't tend to go well together.

Comment: actually I never thought of being able to set the default to a function :O

Comment: Faster as in "Real-World Time" or Faster as in "Fewer Lines"?  If it's the former, what is your target time and how far off are you?

Comment: It is the case of fewer lines, sorry, will update the question :)

Comment: You are aware of how a [horribly bad choice](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) `NEWID()` based uniqueifier clustered keys are, aren't you?

Comment: @RemusRusanu - no I was not aware. In the database I am working all the uniqueidentifiers are clustered. Doubt I should touch and change that.

Comment: At the very least use [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) for the DEFAULT constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep naming your constraints (and you should), I don't think we can reduce it below 2 statements:

```
create table T (
    Col1 varchar(10) not null
)
go
insert into T (Col1)
values ('abc'),('def')
go
ALTER TABLE T ADD [id] [uniqueidentifier] constraint DF_T_id DEFAULT(NEWID()) NOT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE T ADD constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
go
drop table T
```

Note, that I've added a name for the default constraint. Also, this ensures that new rows also have `id` values assigned. As I said in my comment, it's usually preferable to avoid having columns with values generated by `NEWID()` clustered - it leads to lots of fragmentation. If you want to avoid that, consider [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx).

If you don't care about constraint names, you can do it as a single query:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD [id] [uniqueidentifier] DEFAULT(NEWID()) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: Remus Rusanu suggested that NEWID() + clustered = BAD. Can you say a word on that?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - I've mentioned that twice myself, and included a suggested replacement at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: I have also seen `[id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL` - does that work the same as NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID() or is different from both of them?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - `ROWGUIDCOL` is a separate concept - used to mark one `uniqueidentifier` column in a table as "special" - it's used as part of replication. By itself, it doesn't provide a value to the column.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain. I learned 2 related and one unrelated, but very important thing with this question :) Thanks so much!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE T ADD [id] [uniqueidentifier] CONSTRAINT DF_T_id DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` works fine to do it in one operation as both named constraints.